Two forms of transformation of Christoffel Symbols
There are 2 forms of Transformation of Christoffel Symbols found on multiple GR books:
$$
\Gamma^c_{ab} = \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial y^a} \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial y^b} \frac{\partial y^c}{\partial x^n} \Gamma^n_{lu} + \frac{\partial^2 x^n}{\partial y^a \partial y^b} \frac{\partial y^c}{\partial x^n} \quad (1)
$$
$$
\Gamma^c_{ab} = \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial y^a} \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial y^b} \frac{\partial y^c}{\partial x^n} \Gamma^n_{lu} - \frac{\partial^2 y^c}{\partial x^n \partial y^b} \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial y^a} \quad (2)
$$
I know how to prove (1) but I need (2) to prove another question (covariant derivative of a vector behave like a covariant vector)
But I don't know how to prove:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x^n}{\partial y^a \partial y^b} \frac{\partial y^c}{\partial x^n} = - \frac{\partial^2 y^c}{\partial x^n \partial y^b} \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial y^a}
$$
Any help is appreciated!
